Replacing "is" with "is not" in Java
I'm in college and our professor gave us this exercise where the user should input a sentence such as "Life is great" (positiveInput in this case) and we should replace the word "is" with "is not" (negativeOutput).
I've written code to do this, but it turns "Life is great" into "Life is not s great". Can anyone explain to me why is this extra "s" showing?
This is my code:
public void compute() {
  for (int i = 0; i < positiveInput.length(); i++) {
    if (
      (positiveInput.charAt(i-1) == ' ') &&
      (positiveInput.charAt(i) == 'i') &&
      (positiveInput.charAt(i+1) == 's') &&
      (positiveInput.charAt(i+2) == ' ')
    ) {
      sb.append(positiveInput.charAt(i));
      sb.append(positiveInput.charAt(i+1));
      sb.append(' ');
      sb.append("not");
    } else {
      sb.append(positiveInput.charAt(i));
    }
  }
  negativeOutput = sb.toString();
}

For some reason, if I put this piece of code inside the if statement, it works correctly, but I don't seem to understand why:
i+=2


When you hit an " is " you append "is" and " not" but on the next iteration, when the current char is the s of the original is, you add it to the string.

This might be a great time for you to learn to use the debugger. I think you could have answered this question yourself if you'd done this.

This code shouldn't execute. According to the docs for charAt: it throws IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index argument is negative or not less than the length of this string. And positiveInput.charAt(i-1) will be negative when i = 0.

code is inserting two additional characters (from input), so the index must be incremented by 2

Basically, this is what is happening:



i
charAt(i)
if(...)
Contents of negativeOutput




0
L
false
L


1
i
false
Li


2
f
false
Lif


3
e
false
Life


4
 
false
Life 


5
i
true
Life  + is not = Life is not


6
s
false
Life is nots


7
 
false
Life is nots 


8
g
false
Life is nots g


9
r
false
Life is nots gr


10
e
false
Life is nots gre


11
a
false
Life is nots grea


12
t
false
Life is nots great



Exactly as you observed, if you put a i += 2 (which is equivalent to i = i + 2), then we will go from i=5 to i=7. As you see in the table above, the 7th character is the space between not and great. Thus, we essentially skip the 6th character - which is this mysterious trailing s-character.
Note: The given code will likely result in a Runtime-exception, due to the charAt(i-1) when i == 0!

There are already answers using the simpler String.replace. However you marked the question with StringBuffer. The class StringBuilder is intended to be a faster successor, with the same API.
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(positiveInput);
int i = sb.indexOf(" is ");
if (i != -1) {
    int insertI = i + " is ".length();
    sb.insert(insertI, "not ");
} 

This solution takes care when " is " does appear zero or one time.
Multiple times would need an other approach.
Also when the text already contains " is not " the code fails.
Using indexOf is more fail-safe, than a for loop as i must be between 1 and length - 3.
Using insert(index, string) allows to insert "not " after the sought " is ".

If you just need to replace "is" with "is not", then what you're really being asked to replace " is " with " is not " (note the spaces on either side), as no sentence is going to start or end with is. And that's something you can do with String.replaceAll without looping or if statements.
It's just a one-liner:
public void compute() {
  negativeOutput = positiveInput.replaceAll(" is ", " is not ")`;
}

There are lots of useful utility methods in the String class, probably worth giving its documentation a read-through to see what else it can do to make your life easier.

Yep, that’s what it is.

Indeed, and no indication that's the kind of sentence the exercise is asking about. (and trivially dealt with if that's what the exercise permits, if OP is willing to look up how to match that. Lots of posts on SO that'll let them get that done)
